# RecyclerView: Null Object Reference at onBindViewHolder item.get(position)

Tags: java, android, database, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

I am getting a Null Pointer Exception that in my opinion might have to do with the method onBindViewHolder() because I think I am getting a null object when calling mItemAddFriends.get(position); You can see my code and classes below.

error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.pmp_vip.personachat.ItemAddFriends.getUsername()' on a null object reference
                  at com.pmp_vip.personachat.ItemViewHolder.bind(ItemViewHolder.java:19)
                  at com.pmp_vip.personachat.RVAdapter$override.onBindViewHolder(RVAdapter.java:31)
```

...

my classes:

- RVAdapter class:

  ```
  public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemViewHolder> {
      private List<ItemAddFriends> mItemAddFriends;

      public RVAdapter(List<ItemAddFriends> mItemAddFriends) {
          this.mItemAddFriends = mItemAddFriends;
      }

      public void setmItemAddFriends(List<ItemAddFriends> mItemAddFriends{
          this.mItemAddFriends = mItemAddFriends;
      }

      @Override
      public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int        viewType) {
          View view =        LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_add_friends,   parent, false);
          return new ItemViewHolder(view);
      }

      @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, int   position) {
          final ItemAddFriends item = mItemAddFriends.get(position);
          itemViewHolder.bind(item);
      }

      @Override
      public int getItemCount() {
          return mItemAddFriends.size();
      }   

      public void setFilter(List<ItemAddFriends> itemAddFriends) {
          mItemAddFriends = new ArrayList<>();
          mItemAddFriends.addAll(itemAddFriends);
          notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
  }
  ```
- ItemViewHolder class:

  ```
  public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      public TextView username_textView;
      public TextView name_textView;

      public ItemViewHolder(View view) {
          super(view);

          username_textView = (TextView)   view.findViewById(R.id.item_username);
          name_textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
      }

      public void bind(ItemAddFriends itemAddFriends) {
          username_textView.setText(itemAddFriends.getUsername());
          name_textView.setText(itemAddFriends.getName());
      }
  }
  ```
- AddFriendsActivity class:

  ```
  public class AddFriendsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

      private RecyclerView recyclerView;
      private List<ItemAddFriends> mItemAddFriends;
      private RVAdapter adapter;

      private static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://10.0.2.2/";

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_friends);

         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

          mItemAddFriends = new ArrayList<>();

          recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
          LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
          layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
          recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
          adapter = new RVAdapter(mItemAddFriends);
          recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add, menu);
          final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_add);
          final SearchView searchView = (SearchView)       MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
          searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
           searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.e_username));
          searchView.setIconified(false);
          searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
          searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onClose() {
                  finish();
                  return true;
              }
          });

          MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
                  new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                      @Override
                      public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                          adapter.setFilter(mItemAddFriends);
                          return true;
                      }

                      @Override
                      public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item)   {
                          return true;
                      }
                  });
          return true;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          switch (item.getItemId()) {
              case android.R.id.home:
                  finish();
                  return true;
              default:
                  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
          }
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
          return false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
          final List<ItemAddFriends> filteredItemList =  filter(mItemAddFriends, newText);
          adapter.setmItemAddFriends(filteredItemList);
          adapter.setFilter(filteredItemList);
          return true;
      }

      private List<ItemAddFriends> filter(List<ItemAddFriends> list,  String query) {
          query = query.toLowerCase();
          final List<ItemAddFriends> filteredItemList = new ArrayList<>();

          SearchUser searchUser = new SearchUser(query);
          searchUser.execute();
          filteredItemList.add(searchUser.getItemAddFriends());

         return filteredItemList;
      }

      private class SearchUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

          String query;
          ItemAddFriends itemAddFriends;

          public SearchUser(String query) {
              this.query = query;
          }

          public ItemAddFriends getItemAddFriends() {
              return itemAddFriends;
          }

          @Override
          protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
              String jsonData = "";
              String result = "";
              JSONObject object = null;

              try {
                  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                  FormBody.Builder builder = new FormBody.Builder()
                          .add("query", query);

                  RequestBody formBody = builder.build();

                  Request request = new Request.Builder()
                          .url(SERVER_ADDRESS + "search.user.php")
                          .post(formBody)
                          .build();

                  Response responses = null;

                  try {
                      responses = client.newCall(request).execute();
                      jsonData = responses.body().string();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }

                  try {
                      JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                      JSONArray Jarray = Jobject.getJSONArray("users");

                      for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
                          object = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                          result = object.getString("firstname");
                     }

                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                 }
              } catch (Exception e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }

              itemAddFriends = new ItemAddFriends(result, result);

              return null;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

I think everything works except for the issue that the method bind() in the ItemViewHolder class name_textView.setText(itemAddFriends.getName()); causes a Null Pointer Exception.
I don't know how to fix it.

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
itemAddFriends
```

in your bind method of your ItemViewHolder class is null. Try debugging from where you initialize the "List mItemAddFriends", and see why it has a null value.